# Get the ith bit - is % or & faster?

Tags: performance, math, assembly, bit-manipulation, bit

I'd like to know which of the following is faster for getting the i'th rightmost bit of integer x, where i starts with 0:

```
x & (1 << i)
x >> i % 2
```

Also curious about why one is faster.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the platform, and the compiler.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth and the optimization flags.

Comment: In a stupid implementation the first would likely be faster, since `&` is (possibly) faster than `%`, and shifts are about a wash, left or right.  But on some processors `&` and `%` are equally fast, and, more to the point, all but the dumbest compilers would convert `% 2` to a mask operation.

Comment: Note: Those two are very different. You probably meant `(x >> i) % 2`, as written, it's equivalent to `x >> (i % 2)`.

Comment: The second way is stupid anyway - you're working with bits, so work with bits. Don't hide it behind seemingly normal arithmetic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE**

As commented, this depends on many factors.  Also, you shouldn't care.  On any real program I don't believe you will have concern for such low level details.  Premature optimization is a horrible waste of time.

Also, these are not equal operations unless your concept of equality is only the concept of zero/non-zero.

**But it's a fun exercise**

Using GCC with -O3 and disassembling I see:

```
x & (1 << i)

The first version
Dump of assembler code for function op1:
   0x0000000000000000 <+0>:     mov    %esi,%ecx
   0x0000000000000002 <+2>:     mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000000007 <+7>:     shl    %cl,%eax
   0x0000000000000009 <+9>:     and    %edi,%eax
   0x000000000000000b <+11>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

And

```
x >> i % 2

Dump of assembler code for function op2:
   0x0000000000000010 <+0>:     mov    %esi,%ecx
   0x0000000000000012 <+2>:     sar    %cl,%edi
   0x0000000000000014 <+4>:     mov    %edi,%edx
   0x0000000000000016 <+6>:     shr    $0x1f,%edx
   0x0000000000000019 <+9>:     lea    (%rdi,%rdx,1),%eax
   0x000000000000001c <+12>:    and    $0x1,%eax
   0x000000000000001f <+15>:    sub    %edx,%eax
   0x0000000000000021 <+17>:    retq
```

So that's a `shift left` and an `and` vs a `shift right`, `load effective address`, and an `and` operation.  It seems pretty obvious on this hardware what will be faster, but unless you're on a microcontroller what seems obvious is often not so clear.  Let us test it.

I made a loop of something like ten million calls to the (inlined) operation and was sure to return the sum of the operation results so the compiler wouldn't throw it all away.

```
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ gcc -O3 so.c -o so
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ time ./so

real    0m0.388s
user    0m0.384s
sys     0m0.003s
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ time ./so

real    0m0.384s
user    0m0.380s
sys     0m0.003s
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ vi so.c  // I changed the function to the second one
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ gcc -O3 so.c -o so
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ time ./so

real    0m0.380s
user    0m0.377s
sys     0m0.002s
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ time ./so

real    0m0.380s
user    0m0.379s
```

Well shucks - the exact same.  There's enough hardware in a modern super-scaler processor to hide any difference.

Comment: The compiler produces a different output because the expression behave differently if `x` is signed and negative.

Comment: As I note, they behave differently even for unsigned values unless all you're doing is testing `== 0`.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic way to extract a bit is either

```
(x >> i) & 1
```

which would also work analogously for more than one bit, or

```
x & (1 << i)
```

if you just want to test a single bit.

Note that in C `x` must not be negative (preferably declared unsigned), and if `x` is longer than an `int` you need to specify that 1 is also that long in the second one.

Using `%` will confuse the reader and may have a much worse performance, depending on the compiler.

Comment: `1 & (x >>> i)` this also works.